# Iteration in Python - Create Multiple Combinations

Tags: python, loops, combinations

How should I iterate through a string of lists to create multiple combination of words
Example :

```
b = "elec[t][r][i][c][i][t][y]"
```

I am looking for combinations as below (Should have same order)

```
elec
elect
electr
electri
electric
electrici
electricit
electricity
```

Comment: does the example contain list depth of more than one? like ele[c][[t][r]] ?

Comment: Are the lists always lists of length 1? If so, it seems rather straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: @edusanketdk No, list depth is never more than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = "elec[t][r][i][c][i][t][y]"
ans = ""
for i in b.split("["):
    ans += i[:-1] if i.endswith("]") else i
    print(ans)
```

This would split the string in a list of strings which you can consecutively add and print to get the output:

```
elec
elect
electr
electri
electric
electrici
electricit
electricity
```

Comment: @deepali sharma, did that answer your question?

Comment: Welome, you should consider accepting the solution now that you find it helpful :)